# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers.' #253

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I am a mac user who has encountered this issue `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers.'` and I was just trying to use pyttsx3 for a simple task and this error came and I have seen answers for this but all of them are realted to windows and there is not a solution which supports Mac OS, Here is the full Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s.sinha@aics.espritscholen.nl/PycharmProjects/AI First/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/s.sinha@aics.espritscholen.nl/PycharmProjects/AI First/venv/lib/Stack Overflow Question.py", line 7, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init('')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/s.sinha@aics.espritscholen.nl/PycharmProjects/AI First/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/s.sinha@aics.espritscholen.nl/PycharmProjects/AI First/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/s.sinha@aics.espritscholen.nl/PycharmProjects/AI First/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers.'
```

I tried methods like renistalling pyttsx3 but it still didn't solve the problem .

Comment: are you using a virtual environment, if yes check its present in there by running pip list

Comment: No I tired both ways even if i use a Venv then also it says the same error and even if i don't then the it says the same error too.